# python recursively merge 2 list in sorted order

Tags: python, list, sorting, recursion

I want to sort a single list as I'm creating it from 2 sorted list recursively.  This is what I have written so far:

```
def list_creation (list_one,list_two):
   if list_one == [] and list_two == []:
       return []
   else:
       if list_one != [] and list_two != []:
           if list_one[0] <= list_two[0]:
               return [list_one[0],list_two[0]] + list_creation(list_one[1:],list_two[1:])
           else:
               return [list_two[0],list_one[0]] + list_creation(list_one[1:],list_two[1:])

print(list_creation([10,11,12,13],[14,15,16,17]))
print(list_creation([3,6,9,12],[4,8,12,16]))
```

This works for the second print statement but not for the first.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is this `merge` function defined?

Comment: You cannot assume that you can take from both lists every iteration. You need to handle the case where the second element in `list_one` is less than the first element in `list_two`. The way to do this is to take one element at a time, from the list with the smaller head.

Comment: sorry merge was a typo.

Comment: What if `list_one == []` and `list_two != []`? Or vice versa? You don't handle those cases currently. It would return None.

Comment: I do, in the rest of my code my question was just pertaining to the case when I had 2 list.  Thanks for being so thorough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect. You should do the appending item by item, not in pairs. For example, consider `[1,2]` and `[3,4]`. Your algorithm will pair `[1,3,2,4]`, which is obviously wrong. The main idea is to first prepend the `1`, and call **recursively** the algorithm with the remaining lists, i.e. `[2]` and `[3,4]`. Of course you should also consider the case where one of the lists is empty and the other one is not.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I can't believe I didn't see this earlier!!